# Int object is not iterable TypeError in python when using lists

Tags: python

I am not sure why this error is coming up. I am using repl.it and my code seems to work fine up until line 12. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#Global constants
TIMESTORUN=20
#This program analyzes 20 inputted numbers and prints them like so: lowest, highest, total, average.
def main():
  userInput()
def userInput():
  counter=1
  listOfNumbers=[0]*20
  while counter<=TIMESTORUN:
    listOfNumbers=int(input('Enter a number '))
    counter+=1
  minNumber=min(listOfNumbers)
  print('The smallest number is', minNumber)
  maxNumber=max(listOfNumbers)
  print('The largest number is', maxNumber)
  total=0
  for number in listOfNumbers:
    total+=number
  print('The sum is', total)
  average=sum/len(listOfNumbers)
  print('The average is', average)
main()
```

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message. As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Also, why is there is so little whitespace in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few small mistakes:

- You probably don't want to hardcode `20` here:

  ```
  listOfNumbers=[0]*20
  ```

  But use `TIMESTORUN`, too:

  ```
  listOfNumbers=[0]*TIMESTORUN
  ```
- Now your "main" mistake. You assigned the user input (one single number) to the name of the whole list `listOfNumbers`:

  ```
  listOfNumbers=int(input('Enter a number '))
  ```

  Instead, you need to assign to only one element of the list, using your index `counter`:

  ```
  listOfNumbers[counter-1]=int(input('Enter a number '))
  ```
- `sum` is a built-in function and not the name you chose for your sum:

  ```
  average=sum/len(listOfNumbers)
  ```

  So use `total` instead:

  ```
  average=total/len(listOfNumbers)
  ```

---

By the way, if you're interested in another approach, you could do everything something like this, too:

```py
count = 20
numbers = [int(input("Enter a number ")) for _ in range(count)]
print("The smallest number is", min(numbers))
print("The largest number is", max(numbers))
print("The sum is", sum(numbers))
print("The average is", sum(numbers) / len(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a list for all the input numbers you are requesting from the user, it's currently not a **list**, maybe create one and append to it and then you can take the min of the values like this:

```
 getMinvals = min(listofnums)
 #listofnums is a list with all the numbers
```

Seems you have a list but aren't actually making use of it, so maybe to fix the main issue do this:

```
getNums = int(input("Enter numbers:"))
getMinvals = listOfNumbers.append(getNums)
```

then take the min value of that list.

Note:

The code is dependent on a hard-code, maybe make it dynamic or either wise it will be a fixed list, consider adding a proper `__main__` method so it's clear to users what the real issue is, alongside with a full **traceback** error statement to tell us which line the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

In this line you recast your list to an int, you should correct this line to sent its output to either append to the list of numbers or to replace one index in this list.

```
   listOfNumbers=int(input('Enter a number '))
```